# How to stop Motor6Ds from automatically adding to rigs

Tags: roblox

I'm making a ragdoll system for R15 rigs on Roblox Studio and while there are no Motor6Ds on the ragdoll in the server, the client generates Motor6Ds on the ragdoll, putting the dead rig into a sort of platform-stand position instead of letting the ball-in-socket and hinges flop around. How do I make it like, NOT do this? I wrote a localscript that deletes all Motor6Ds it finds in the workspace 'corpses' folder that i've designated for ragdolls, but it still glitches out and does not update fast enough to keep the Motor6Ds out of the ragdoll, so sometimes they come back for a split second and reset the ragdoll's position, then lets it flop again.

TLDR: How can I make it so Motor6Ds don't generate into R15 rigs on clientside, particularly when the player's character is nearby said rig?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `StarterPlayerScripts` or `StarterGui` as a LocalScript.

```lua
game.Players.LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
   char.DescendantAdded:Connect(function(thing)
      if thing == nil then return end
      if thing:IsA("Motor6D") then thing:Destroy() end
   end)
end)
```

This should remove any Motor6D's added to your local character.

Comment: The character's motor6ds are not the problem - the problem is that OTHER rigs in the workspace are generating motor6ds. For instance, an enemy whose corpse is left over after they died, when the player approaches that dead body, the dead body regains its motor6ds - not the player character. I appreciate the help, though!!